# An array from JavaScript to servlet

Tags: javascript, arrays, jsp, servlets

I have a problem with receiving data from JavaScript into a servlet. In my page, a user can generate an array with strings (using JavaScript). I want to receive this data into my servlet. I don't have any idea how to do it. Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 3):

You have to serialise the data.

You could encode it as JSON ([json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) provides a cross browser library that will do this) and then have a Java JSON library to decode it at the other end.

Alternatively, you can use the application/x-www-form-urlencoded encoding (as used when you submit a form) of `name=value&name=othervalue` (make sure you [encode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) each part).

Once the data is serialised, you have to make an HTTP request. The simplest way is to put the data in a query string and set `location.href`. If you want to send the data without leaving the page, then look into [XMLHttpRequest](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/), usually abstracted via [a library that irons out the differences between browsers](http://microjs.com/#ajax) (bigger libraries that do lots of other stuff include [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/) and [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)).